# How can I format the boost path object without quotes?

Tags: c++, boost, path

Here is my code:

```
fs::path datadir = ...;
std::string dataDirOption((boost::format("--datadir=%1%") % datadir).str());
```

For `datadir=="c:/db"` I get `dataDirOption=="--datadir=\"c:/db\""`, instead of `"--datadir=c:/db"`

Is it possible to tell `boost::filesystem::path` to skip the quotes when being formatted?

Now, I know I can substitute `datadir.string()` for `datadir` and get rid of the quotes in this way, but I am wondering whether I can do so without the extra string.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Boost is just playing safe, just in case there are e.g. spaces in the path.

Comment: I understand it, but I am composing a command line for the mysqld database engine and it really dislikes the extra quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest another option: post processing.

```
boost::replace_all(dataDirOption, "\"", "");
```

This way you can *easily* switch to another quote character like `'` for example.

Answer (score 6):

No it is not, is is a [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5702) files on the boost framework version 1.47.0 which has not yet been given a milestone on when to be fixed.

The workaround however is:

```
std::cout << path("/foo/bar.txt").filename().string()
```

Answer (score 3):

[The `%` operator for `format` uses the `<<` stream-insertion operator for user-defined types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#user-defined), and [the documentation tells us](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-inserter-extractor) it's effectively the following for `path`:

```
os << boost::io::quoted(p.string<std::basic_string<Char>>(), static_cast<Char>('&'));
```

To leave out the quotes, you need to pass something different to the `format` object, such as the output of the `string` method as you've already discovered.